# BeautifulSoup 4 is inserting closing tags on me

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am pulling html code from [yahoo](http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/today.html) and BS4 (4.3.2) is inserting closing tags after the "eps estimate" including a closing body tag. This results in it not parsing the relevant info from the table

Original Source Excerpt:

```
<b>Earnings
Announcements for
Wednesday, January 15</b></td></tr><tr
bgcolor=dcdcdc><td><font
face=arial
size=-1><b>Company</b></font></td><td><font
face=arial
size=-1><b>Symbol</b></font></td><td
align=center><font
face=arial
size=-1><b>EPS<br>Estimate*</font></b></td><td
align=center><font
face=arial
size=-1><b>Time</b></font></td><td
align=center><font
face=arial
size=-1><b>Add
to
My<br>Calendar</b></font></td><td
align=center><font`...
```

After BeautifulSoup(html):

```
 <td align="center">
          <font face="arial" size="-1">
           <b>
            EPS
            <br>
             Estimate*
            </br>
           </b>
          </font>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </p>
  </p>
  </p>
 </br>
</br>
</link>
</body>
</html>
<td align="center"><font face="arial" size="-1">
 <b>
Time
</b>
</font>
</td>
```

....

Comment: yes.  bs4 repairs broken tags ... why is that a problem?

Comment: Are you saying it worked before? If so, how? If not, why not just change the way you parse it?

Comment: `bs4` can use three different underlying parsers. See [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). They all handle broken HTML differently. Try them all.

Comment: Also, if Yahoo is really serving this code on a URL meant to be scraped, file a bug with them.

Comment: That being said, if the terms & conditions specifically forbid scraping this site (which is pretty common), they may have deliberately crafted the HTML so it works in all the major browsers but is a huge pain to parse.